# YOLOv3 & OpenCV dnn - Inconsistent shape for ConcatLayer in function 'getMemoryShapes'

Tags: python, opencv, yolo, darknet

I'm having trouble loading YOLOv3's into OpenCV's dnn module. I'm following [this tutorial](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/11/12/yolo-object-detection-with-opencv/) but instead of using the full YOLOv3 I'm using Tiny YOLOv3 trained on my own dataset.

On line 84 `layerOutputs = net.forward(ln)` I get the openCV error:

```sh
[ERROR:0] global /io/opencv/modules/dnn/src/dnn.cpp (3066) getLayerShapesRecursively OPENCV/DNN: [Concat]:(concat_20): getMemoryShapes() throws exception. inputs=2 outputs=1/1
[ERROR:0] global /io/opencv/modules/dnn/src/dnn.cpp (3069) getLayerShapesRecursively     input[0] = [ 1 128 28 28 ]
[ERROR:0] global /io/opencv/modules/dnn/src/dnn.cpp (3069) getLayerShapesRecursively     input[1] = [ 1 256 27 27 ]
[ERROR:0] global /io/opencv/modules/dnn/src/dnn.cpp (3073) getLayerShapesRecursively     output[0] = [ 1 128 28 28 ]
[ERROR:0] global /io/opencv/modules/dnn/src/dnn.cpp (3075) getLayerShapesRecursively Exception message: OpenCV(4.2.0) /io/opencv/modules/dnn/src/layers/concat_layer.cpp:102: error: (-201:Incorrect size of input array) Inconsistent shape for ConcatLayer in function 'getMemoryShapes'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "yolo-server.py", line 86, in <module>
    layerOutputs = net.forward(ln)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.2.0) /io/opencv/modules/dnn/src/layers/concat_layer.cpp:102: error: (-201:Incorrect size of input array) Inconsistent shape for ConcatLayer in function '
```

where `ln = [ln[i[0] - 1] for i in net.getUnconnectedOutLayers()]`

Here's [my code](https://pastebin.com/RLH2E3tv) & here's [the cfg](https://pastebin.com/QEeE032R) Here is [the weights](https://gofile.io/?c=7e3Fz5) I used.

**Attempt @ Soln**

I tried it using COCO & got results, meaning i highly suspect it has to do with the CFG file? But when I try my cfg & weights using darknet it works - so I guess there's a bigger error I'm making inside my cfg that darknet skips over? I've also scoured the internet but couldn't find anything digestible to the error I'm making.